# can not set value to string from onPostExcecute in AsyncTask android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

this is the class for reading json string from web

```
  {

  public class JSONmethod extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
  {

   public  String result_string;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    try {
        URL url;
        url = new URL(params[0]);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        String line= "";
        buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null)
        {
            buffer.append(line);
        }
        return buffer.toString();

    }

    catch(MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
        try {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);


    result_string=result;

}



public String result_string_josn()
{
    return result_string;
}
 }
```

method "result_string_json()" return null string

i want to use this class frequntly for reading the json string from the web

so i made this method for return string which will returns from onPostExecute

this is the class where i want that value which is generate in post execute through method or anything else

simple.java

```
 package com.bhatti.bis;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.Toast;


public class simple extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple);

    JSONmethod j = new JSONmethod();
    j.execute("here is json string");


    Toast.makeText(this,j.result_string_josn(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Comment: Did you try my solution? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) library. It's very easy to use and will perfectly fix your problem:

First create a simple class for your Event:
public class MyEvent{
    private String data;

```
public MyEvent(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public String getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

Then in your Activity or wherever, register and unregister the EventBus, as explained in the docs.

Now post the appropriate event:

```
   @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    EventBus.getDefault().post(new MyEvent(jsonArray.toString()));
}
```

All that's left for you to do is to listen for that event wherever you want (in another Activity, Fragment, Service - that's what makes EventBus great):

```
@Subscribe
public void onMyEvent(MyEvent myEvent){
    String data = myEvent.getData();
    //do whatever you wish with the text (e.g. make a toast, write it somewhere)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Async Task is asynchronous task, please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony_%28computer_programming%29

Remove `Toast` just after :

```
JSONmethod j = new JSONmethod();
j.execute("here is json string");
```

And put it in onPostExecute :

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Toast.makeText(this,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: i want that value in another class not in same class

Comment: Add a callback to get result

Answer (score 0):

Android handles input events/tasks with a single User Interface (UI) thread and the thread is called Main thread. Main thread cannot handle concurrent operations as it handles only one event/operation at a time.For [detail read this tutorials](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/what-is-asynctask-in-android/)

```
JSONmethod jSONmethod = new JSONmethod();
jSONmethod.execute("Your json string");



public class JSONmethod extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
  {

   public  String result_string;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    try {
        URL url;
        url = new URL(params[0]);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        String line= "";
        buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null)
        {
            buffer.append(line);
        }
        return buffer.toString();

    }

    catch(MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
        try {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);


  Log.d("JSONmethod","result = "+result);

}


 }
```